# Proving arbitrary intersection of normal subgroups is a normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $K = \cap_{i \in I} K_i$ for normal set subgroups $K_i$.

Most of the proofs I found online just proved one side: $gKg^{-1}\subset K$ and left the other side untouched. For example, the one with a lot of upvotes is: [Show that the intersection of two normal subgroup of $G$ is normal subgroup of $G$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2249474/show-that-the-intersection-of-two-normal-subgroup-of-g-is-normal-subgroup-of)

Now, if G is finite, it is not hard to prove $ K = gKg^{-1} $ by observing that the map from K to $gKg^{-1}$ is injective. However, if K is infinite, such result may not hold. Examples can be found here: [Conjugate subgroup strictly contained in the initial subgroup?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107862/conjugate-subgroup-strictly-contained-in-the-initial-subgroup)

This has left me in deep confusion. If the cardinality of K is not specified, does this result hold?

Comment: What is your definition of a normal subgroup? Isn't it that $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ if for any $k\in K, g\in G$ we have $gkg^{-1}\in K$? If so there is nothing more you need to show.

Comment: @Snaw The definition I learned is that $gKg^{-1}=K$, which at first is a stronger condition.

Comment: As you will have seen from the answer below, the point lies with the quantifier. If $g K g^{-1}  \subseteq K$ **for all**  $g \in G$, then $g K g^{-1} = K$ for all $g \in G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $gKg^{-1}\subset K$ for all $g$, then for any $g\in G, k\in K$, we have $$h = g^{-1} k (g^{-1})^{-1} \in g^{-1} K g \subset K$$ hence $k = ghg^{-1}\in gKg^{-1}$.